# Why do "cssFloat" and "float" styles not behave the same?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got some code which writes the innerHTML of a TD cell using

```
<img src='0.gif' style='cssFloat:left'>
```

I'm trying to rewrite this code using a library that generates the image tag for me, which in effect is doing something like this:

```
img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = '0.gif'
img.style['cssFloat'] = 'left'
```

However, when I do this I am seeing different behavior: the images aren't lining up properly, and when I inspect the HTML source in Chrome's debugger tools it says the style is "float: left" instead of "cssFloat: left".  If I manually edit it in the debugger tools to "cssFloat: left" then it correctly floats the image and everything lines up correctly.

Why is setting cssFloat programatically changing the style to "float" instead?  And why does it make a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS property *is* [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) - as such, the unknown/invalid "cssFloat" property in the style attribute is ignored.

However, the CSS `float` property is *mapped* as `cssFloat` in the DOM to avoid reserved words (notably, `float`). The MDN link above contains this note:

> *If you're referring to this property from JavaScript as a member of the element.style object, you must spell it as cssFloat*. .. This is an exception to the rule that the name of the DOM member is the camel-case name of the dash-separated CSS name (and is due to the fact that "float" is a reserved word in JavaScript ..)

This is a similar to class (CSS) vs `className` (DOM) and other "exceptional" rules.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's bizarre, because...

Well, first I should explain that `float` is a reserved word in JS. That means you can't just write `something.float`. So they decided to make it `something.cssFloat` instead.

`style="cssFloat:left"` is incorrect and should not work (with the Inspector citing something like "unknown property")

So why it works like that for you is beyond me... but hopefully this information helps!

Answer (score 2):

Answer: just delete that line:

```
img.style['cssFloat'] = 'left'
```

And it will work.

#### Explanation:

`cssFloat` in javascript = `float` in CSS.

`cssFloat` css property doesn't exists. For example in chrome debugger:
[image]

1) When you write `img.style['cssFloat'] = 'left'` in css it would be `<img src="0.gif" style="float: left;" />` which working way to set 'float'.

2) When you write `<img src="0.gif" style="cssFloat: left;" />`, where 'cssFloat' property doesn't exists. So you can shorten this code to just `<img src="0.gif" />`